# MockK's "every" "returns null" not returning "null" but a NetworkInfo object with null and false values

Tags: unit-testing, android-testing, mockk

In my unit test I am calling the following:

```
    every { connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo } returns null
```

but when I debug I get a NetworkInfo object filled with null and false values

```
networkInfo = {NetworkInfo@9780}"[type: null[null], state: null/null, reason: unspecified), extra: (none), failover: false, available: false, roaming: false]"
```

therefore this null check in my implementation does not yield false and I cannot verify the "false" path.

```
val networkInfo = connectivityManager?.activeNetworkInfo
if (networkInfo != null) { ... }
```

I am calling this deprecated getActiveNetworkInfo() method because I need to support Android 8.0 8.1 and 9.

what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the problem, the code above works, my problem was that I did not pass my mocked objects correctly so the mocked code never was executed.